# Why aren't Paypal donations allowed in some parts of Europe?

Tags: paypal, donation, regulation

I know that Paypal donations aren't available for Croatia, and maybe some other parts of Europe, but I always wondered why is it that way?

Are there some legal issues or what? I'd really like to know and I can't find some explanatory answer other than "No, it's not available in your country".

Can someone explain?

Comment: should be different soon now that Croatia is in the Euro Zone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any source/destination is considered in violation of US sanctions or Anti-Money laundering statutes, then PayPal as a financial institution bound by those regulations will have deny the transactions. Its a never ending cat and mouse, where a country will show up on the list one day and a few months later they are not on there; for example what @CQM mentioned. Many countries in the middle east, africa for example are part of the exclusion.